# .net ontextchanged, wait until user is done writing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a searchbox that queries a database and shows the results in a box below. This is kinda slow when I use the ontextchanged event, cause the database gets queried each time a new letter is written.

How can I make it only do the query when the user is done writing, or each time the user takes a small break?

Comment: VB.NET doesn't have a searchbox control as far I know, what do you mean by searchbox? what control are you using?

Comment: My bad, it is a normal TextBox field, that fires a custom made search function on "TextChanged".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to record the time that the last OnTextChanged occured.  And if the current time greater than N, then call the web service.

Another way, is to start a repeating time for every N milliseconds and then check the Text with the lastText and if not equal call the web service.  If you do this, use System.Windows.Form.Timer so that your callback is executing on the UI when you get the current Text from the search box.

Comment: Your first paragraph's solution isn't going to work - the last keypress won't be registered if it happens when `current time < N`.  The second solution would work, though.

Comment: @dan, that's why I included it.  I wanted OP to try something simple first.

Comment: @Sjark, glad I could be of some help. Perhaps you could post you solution to help the next person!

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this is to fire off a Timer each time a key is changed.  I track the number of times the text has been changed and compare it to the number of times the Timers have expired.  If the two numbers are equal, call the method.  NOTE:  MySearchMethod() is the method to fire after the user stops typing and txtQuickSearch is the ID of the text box the user is typing into.

```
Private mint_LastReceivedTimerID As Integer = 0
Private mint_LastInitializedTimerID As Integer = 0

Private Sub txtQuickSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles txtQuickSearch.TextChanged
    'Increment the counter for the number of times the textbox has been changed
    mint_LastInitializedTimerID = mint_LastInitializedTimerID + 1

    'Wait longer for shorter strings or strings without spaces
    Dim intMilliseconds As Integer = 500
    If txtQuickSearch.Text.Length >= 6 Then
        intMilliseconds = 250
    End If
    If txtQuickSearch.Text.Contains(" ") = True And txtQuickSearch.Text.EndsWith(" ") = False Then
        intMilliseconds = 175
    End If

    Dim objTimer As New System.Timers.Timer(intMilliseconds)
    AddHandler objTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf txtQuickSearch_TimerElapsed

    objTimer.AutoReset = False
    objTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub txtQuickSearch_TimerElapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    'Increment the counter for the number of times timers have elapsed
    mint_LastReceivedTimerID = mint_LastReceivedTimerID + 1

    'If the total number of textbox changes equals the total number of times timers have elapsed (fire method for only the latest character change)
    If mint_LastReceivedTimerID = mint_LastInitializedTimerID Then
        'Fire method on the Main UI Thread
        Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() MySearchMethod(), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps wire a Timer object up with, say, a 500ms (half-a-second) interval, and have it start when the .onTextChanged event fires. Then when the timer 'ticks', use that event to fire the query to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Const WaitInterval As Integer = 5   '5 seconds <-- change this to control speed
Dim WithEvents MyTimer As New Timers.Timer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MyTimer.Interval = WaitInterval * 1000
    MyTimer.AutoReset = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    MyTimer.Stop()
    MyTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub MyTimer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles MyTimer.Elapsed

    '' -- call your method to query database here --

End Sub
```